# Better way to write a list of && checks?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a better way to write this code:

```
def down_up(array, player)
    7.downto(3).each do |row|
      8.times do |column|
        if array[row][column] == player
          if array[row - 1][column] == player && array[row - 2][column] == player && array[row - 3][column] == player
            return :winner
          end   
        end  
      end   
    end
    return :nothing_yet
  end
```

specifically this line:

```
if array[row - 1][column] == player && array[row - 2][column] == player && array[row - 3][column] == player
```

If a cell matches, this checks to see if 3 consecutive rows also match - but there's a lot of redundancy.  What's a good general way to refactor a list of `&&` conditions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write as below :

```
 if [1,2,3].all?{|i| array[row - i][column] == player }
```

Answer (score 3):

If that lines repeat a lot you may want to make method:

```
def consecutive_rows(array, row, column)
   array[row - 1][column] == player && array[row - 2][column] == player && array[row - 3][column] == player
end
```

and in your code:

```
return :winner if consecutive_rows(array, row, column)
```

Comment: i went with Arup's answer, but used your `return :winner if` also, so thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

One thing clearly not elegant about your code is that you are separating `array[row]` conditioning and `array[row - 1]`, `array[row - 2]`, `array[row - 3]` conditions. They should be put together as a condition on `array[row - 3, 4]`.

```
def down_up(array, player)
  (3..7).any?{|i| (0..7).any?{|j| array[i - 3, 4].all?{|a| a[j] == player}}} ?
  :winner : :nothing_yet
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you might want to rearrange the method:

```
def down_up(array, player)
  rows    = 7.downto(3).to_a
  columns = 7.downto(0).to_a

  rows.product(columns).detect(-> { :nothing_yet }) do |row, column|
    next unless array[row][column] == player

    if [1,2,3].all?{|i| array[row - i][column] == player }
      :winner
    end
  end
end
```